# Why might Xcode think an instance method is a class method?

Tags: objective-c, methods

I am trying to compile some code where I have a class called Card.  It has a method called

`-(void)setSuit: (NSString *)suit`

It is an instance method, but when I say 
`[Card setSuit:@"Diamonds"]`

Xcode says: `warning: "Card" may not respond to method +setSuit`

And my program doesn't work.  I think that Xcode thinks setSuit is a class method, as it says in the warning, so how do I tell it that I am talking about an instance method?

Or maybe that isn't the problem at all, I don't really know as I have never encountered this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
[Card setSuit:@"Diamonds"]
```

If `Card` is the class, then the above line will try to call a method on the class, not an instance. You'll need to call a method on an instance instead, say:

```
Card *card = [[Card alloc] init];
[card setSuit:@"Diamonds"];
```

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to send `-setSuit:` to the `Card` class.  You probably want to send that message to an *instance* of `Card`, not the class.